# Query in VB.net sometimes doesn't work

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, email

I have a functionality which saves the information from a webform to the database, which is working fine.

This is my code for save functionality in Onspec.aspx.vb page

```
   Public Sub SaveClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        If Not Page.IsValid Then
            litMessage.Text = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Try

            Dim sName As String = ""

            With EmployerCandidate

                .employerid = Master.Employer.ID
                .employeruserid = 0

                Try
                    .CVID = DocId
                Catch
                End Try

                .Name = uxName.Text
                .SurName = uxSurname.Text

                Try
                    .PostCode = uxPostcode.Text
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try

                .Email = uxEmail.Text

                Try
                    .MobileNo = uxMobileNo.Text
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try

                .OnSpec = True

                .OnSpecType = uxOnSpecCategory.SelectedItem.Text
                .Source = uxSourceID.SelectedItem.Text

                .LastEmployer = uxEmployer.Text
                .LastJobTitle = uxJobtitle.Text

                .Profile = uxProfile.Text.Trim

            End With

               ' email()


            ResetForm()

            panForm.Visible = False
            panUpload.Visible = True

            uxSubmit.Visible = False
            uxUpload.Visible = True

            litMessage.Text = "Thank you for submitting your details! We'll be in touch when appropriate vacancy arises. <a href='#' onclick='parent.$.colorbox.close()'>Close</a>"
            UploadPanel.Visible = False


            Response.Redirect("onspec-complete.aspx?e=" & Master.Employer.ID)



        Catch ex As Exception
            litMessage.Text = Core.Helper.FancyMessage("Error as occurred - " & ex.Message.ToString, "ERROR")
        End Try


    End Sub
```

Now,  I want to send emails along with saving the data in the database so I added the following lines of code before `ResetForm()`.

```
Dim specmatch As DataRow = DB.GetRow("SELECT  TOP 1 name,email,password FROM  [user] usr JOIN employeruser empUsr ON usr.id = empUsr.userid WHERE empUsr.empusertype = 1 AND empUsr.employerid = @eid ", DB.SIP("eid", LocalHelper.UserEmployerID))
```

If my query returns a value then I want to send email by calling the email function.

```
        If specmatch IsNot Nothing Then
            email()
        End If
```

But in this line of code the *employerid* value is sometimes empty. It can't pick the id therefore it is returning an empty row. And therefore it's not calling the email function.

This id is the same as

```
.employerid = Master.Employer.ID
```

But if I replace the `LocalHelper.UserEmployerID` with `Master.Employer.ID` the form gives an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

employerid is an integer value.

I have also tried to add the following lines of code in this page(Onspec.aspx.vb)

```
Public ReadOnly Property EmployerId() As Integer
    Get
        Return Master.Employer.ID
    End Get
End Property
```

But I get the same error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The above lines of code does not make any difference.

So I replaced `Master.Employer.ID` with `LocalHelper.UserEmployerID`

Where in  localhelper.vb file (under appcode folder) it is determining employerid from the website with following lines of code.

```
Public Shared Function UserEmployerID() As Integer
    If HttpContext.Current.Items("lh_useremployerid") Is Nothing Then
        If LocalHelper.UserTypeCode = "e" Then
            HttpContext.Current.Items("lh_useremployerid") = Core.DB.GetInteger("SELECT employerid FROM employeruser WHERE userid = " & LocalHelper.UserID)
        Else
            HttpContext.Current.Items("lh_useremployerid") = 0
        End If
    End If

    Return HttpContext.Current.Items("lh_useremployerid")
End Function
```

These lines of code has been used in many places and works perfectly fine. In this case as well, it was working fine last Friday and now it's not. There was no changes made.

This is my email function

```
Private Sub email()

    Dim strCandidateName As String = uxName.Text.Trim & " " & uxSurname.Text.Trim
    Dim strCandidateSurname As String = uxSurname.Text
    Dim strCandidateEmail As String = uxEmail.Text.Trim
    Dim strCandidatePhone As String = uxMobileNo.Text.Trim
    Dim strCPass As String = "mpb123"
    Dim strContactType As String = "Speculative Application has been submited on the category of  " & uxOnSpecCategory.SelectedItem.Text
    Dim strContactMessage As String = uxProfile.Text.Trim


    '''''''''''''''''''variable
    Dim qq As String = String.Format("Select top 1 name, email, password FROM [user] WHERE id in (Select userid FROM employeruser WHERE empusertype=1 and employerid= " & LocalHelper.UserEmployerID & ")")

    Dim drow As DataRow = Core.DB.GetRow(qq)

    Dim semail As String = drow.Item("email").ToString
    Dim sname As String = drow.Item("name").ToString
    Dim spass As String = drow.Item("password").ToString


    '''''''''''''''''''variable



    Dim Email As Core.Email

    'New Onspec Candidate Email sent to EmployerUser who is assigned to receive onspec email

    Email = New Core.Email

    With Email
        .ContentID = 99
        .Replacement("ContactName", strCandidateName)
        .Replacement("ContactEmail", strCandidateEmail)
        .Replacement("ContactTelephone", strCandidatePhone)
        .Replacement("ContactType", strContactType)
        .Replacement("ContactMessage", strContactMessage)
        .Replacement("AdminContactName", sname)
        .Replacement("AdminContactEmail", semail)
        .Replacement("SiteName", LocalHelper.AppSetting("sitename"))
        Dim attachments As New Generic.List(Of String)
        If EmployerCandidate.CVID > 0 Then
            Dim doc As New Document(EmployerCandidate.CVID)
            attachments.Add(doc.PathOnDisc)
        End If
        .Attachments = Join(attachments.ToArray(), ";")

        .Send()

    End With



 End Sub
```

GetRow function is defined in my database.vb page like following which is also used in many other places.

```
    Shared Function GetRow(ByVal selectQueryText As String, ByVal ParamArray params As SqlParameter()) As DataRow
        Return GetRowFromDB(selectQueryText, CommandType.Text, params)
    End Function
```

And

```
Shared Function GetRowFromDB(ByVal selectCommandText As String, ByVal selectCommandType As CommandType, ByVal ParamArray params As SqlParameter()) As DataRow
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Try
            conn = GetOpenSqlConnection()

            Return GetRowFromDB(conn, selectCommandText, selectCommandType, params)
        Finally
            If conn IsNot Nothing Then conn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Please suggest ways on how I can organize my code so that it works all the time.

Comment: You need to work out in what way it is failing when it isn't working. Are you encountering an error or is it (correctly) not finding any row results? Also suggest you change GetRowFromDB to use a `Using` statement.

Comment: HI thanks for your comment.. For certain reason i can't debug the code in my local server.. is there any way i can debug the code in live website.. cause this code is inside an iframe.. and it's set on user website.. and it is picking the ID of LocalHelper.UserEmployerID  from that website. ... aand therefor the row is empty..

Comment: Can you add logging into each of your methods to confirm how far each execution is getting and possibly include some non client sensitive data in the log file. Then compare the executions that worked against those that didn't.